# Which firewall rule is considered if i 'drop' first then later adding 'accept' rule. drop or accept?

Tags: centos, networking, security, iptables, firewall

I am restricting the traffic to specific port number using the below firewall rule.

```
   /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port <port_num> -j DROP
```

After sometime i want to allow traffic, so adding the below firewall rule.

```
   /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port <port_num> -j ACCEPT
```

Is it correct or i have to delete the first rule before adding the second. if i dont delete the first rule,both rules are present in the INPUT chain. so which one is considered ? This is in CentOS7, Looking forward for your advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-A` flag appends to the set of rules. Using `-I` inserts a rule either at the beginning of the chain or at the numbered position. Rules are processed in order, so the first rule you added will be processed first and the second will never be actioned.

You can see the full set of rules for your `INPUT` chain with `iptables -nvL INPUT`.

Since you're on CentOS you might want to use its standard [firewall tool](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-setup-a-firewall-with-firewalld-on-centos-7/), `firewalld` instead of the low-level `iptables`.

Also see [iptables and RETURN target](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/191614/100397) for an explanation of rules that terminate a chain and those that don't.

Comment: But some targets, e.g. `LOG` in particular will _not_ terminate processing of the rules. `ACCEPT`, `DROP`, `REJECT` of course will.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so the ACCEPT wont take effect because DROP is added prior. if i want ACCEPT rule to take effect, should i delete DROP rule first and add ACCEPT rule ? or should i add these rules with -I  instead of -A flag so that whichever the latest rule added will take effect.